# How to make discrete Fourier transform (FFT) in numba.njit?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft, numba

Hello fellow programmers

I am trying to make a `discrete Fourier transform` in this `minimal working example` with the `numba.njit` decorator:

```
import numba
import numpy as np
import scipy
import scipy.fftpack

@numba.njit
def main():
    wave = [[[0.09254795,  0.10001078,  0.10744892, 0.07755555,  0.08506225, 0.09254795],
          [0.09907245,  0.10706145,  0.11502401,  0.08302302,  0.09105898, 0.09907245],
          [0.09565098,  0.10336405,  0.11105158,  0.08015589,  0.08791429, 0.09565098],
          [0.00181467,  0.001961,    0.00210684,  0.0015207,   0.00166789, 0.00181467]],
         [[-0.45816267, - 0.46058367, - 0.46289091, - 0.45298182, - 0.45562851, -0.45816267],
          [-0.49046506, - 0.49305676, - 0.49552669, - 0.48491893, - 0.48775223, -0.49046506],
          [-0.47352483, - 0.47602701, - 0.47841162, - 0.46817027, - 0.4709057, -0.47352483],
          [-0.00898358, - 0.00903105, - 0.00907629, - 0.008882, - 0.00893389, -0.00898358]],
         [[0.36561472,  0.36057289,  0.355442,  0.37542627,  0.37056626, 0.36561472],
          [0.39139261,  0.38599531,  0.38050268,  0.40189591,  0.39669325, 0.39139261],
          [0.37787385,  0.37266296,  0.36736003,  0.38801438,  0.38299141, 0.37787385],
          [0.00716892,  0.00707006,  0.00696945,  0.0073613,  0.00726601, 0.00716892]]]

    new_fft = scipy.fftpack.fft(wave)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\python.exe C:/Users/Artur/Desktop/RL_framework/help_functions/test2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Artur/Desktop/RL_framework/help_functions/test2.py", line 25, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 401, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 344, in error_rewrite
    reraise(type(e), e, None)
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\core\utils.py", line 80, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Unknown attribute 'fft' of type Module(<module 'scipy.fftpack' from 'C:\\Users\\Artur\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\scipy\\fftpack\\__init__.py'>)

File "test2.py", line 21:
def main():
    <source elided>

    new_fft = scipy.fftpack.fft(wave)
    ^

[1] During: typing of get attribute at C:/Users/Artur/Desktop/RL_framework/help_functions/test2.py (21)

File "test2.py", line 21:
def main():
    <source elided>

    new_fft = scipy.fftpack.fft(wave)
    ^


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Unfortunately `scipy.fftpack.fft` seems to be a legacy function that is not supported by `numba`. So I searched for alternatives. I found two:

1.
`scipy.fft(wave)` which is the updated version of the above mentioned legacy function. It produces this error output:

```
C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\python.exe C:/Users/Artur/Desktop/RL_framework/help_functions/test2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Artur/Desktop/RL_framework/help_functions/test2.py", line 25, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 401, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 344, in error_rewrite
    reraise(type(e), e, None)
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\core\utils.py", line 80, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Invalid use of Module(<module 'scipy.fft' from 'C:\\Users\\Artur\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\scipy\\fft\\__init__.py'>) with parameters (list(list(list(float64))))
No type info available for Module(<module 'scipy.fft' from 'C:\\Users\\Artur\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\scipy\\fft\\__init__.py'>) as a callable.
[1] During: resolving callee type: Module(<module 'scipy.fft' from 'C:\\Users\\Artur\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\scipy\\fft\\__init__.py'>)
[2] During: typing of call at C:/Users/Artur/Desktop/RL_framework/help_functions/test2.py (21)


File "test2.py", line 21:
def main():
    <source elided>

    new_fft = scipy.fft(wave)
    ^


Process finished with exit code 1
```

2.
`np.fft.fft(wave)` which seems to be supported but also produces an error:

```
C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\python.exe C:/Users/Artur/Desktop/RL_framework/help_functions/test2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Artur/Desktop/RL_framework/help_functions/test2.py", line 25, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 401, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 344, in error_rewrite
    reraise(type(e), e, None)
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\core\utils.py", line 80, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Unknown attribute 'fft' of type Module(<module 'numpy.fft' from 'C:\\Users\\Artur\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\fft\\__init__.py'>)

File "test2.py", line 21:
def main():
    <source elided>

    new_fft = np.fft.fft(wave)
    ^

[1] During: typing of get attribute at C:/Users/Artur/Desktop/RL_framework/help_functions/test2.py (21)

File "test2.py", line 21:
def main():
    <source elided>

    new_fft = np.fft.fft(wave)
    ^


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Do you know a `fft` function, that works with the `numba.njit` decorator?

Comment: I guess `scipy.fft.fft` is a very fast implementation, do you really need to JIT it?

Comment: @tstanisl It would be best if It worked inside `numba.njit` because else I have to do major changes to the program.

Comment: From the numba [listings of numpy function](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/developer/autogen_numpy_listing.html#numpy-fft), numpy fft module isn't supported, so your second case seems quite normal.

Comment: you can use object mode inside a njit function. Of course you won't get any speed up but don't need major changes

Comment: @zariiii9003 will object mode only slow down the fft function or the whole njit function?

Comment: `pyculib.fft` should be supported https://devblogs.nvidia.com/seven-things-numba/

Comment: @norok2 I tried using `pyculib` but it doesn't seem to work in pycharm, at least I can't get it to work. I've created a post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62360236/how-to-import-pyculib-in-pycharm

Answer (score 5):

If you are happy with a 1D DFT you might as well use an FFT.
Here, is reported a Numba-friendly implementation `fft_1d()` working on arbitrary input sizes:

```
import cmath
import numpy as np
import numba as nb


@nb.jit
def ilog2(n):
    result = -1
    if n < 0:
        n = -n
    while n > 0:
        n >>= 1
        result += 1
    return result


@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def reverse_bits(val, width):
    result = 0
    for _ in range(width):
        result = (result << 1) | (val & 1)
        val >>= 1
    return result


@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def fft_1d_radix2_rbi(arr, direct=True):
    arr = np.asarray(arr, dtype=np.complex128)
    n = len(arr)
    levels = ilog2(n)
    e_arr = np.empty_like(arr)
    coeff = (-2j if direct else 2j) * cmath.pi / n
    for i in range(n):
        e_arr[i] = cmath.exp(coeff * i)
    result = np.empty_like(arr)
    for i in range(n):
        result[i] = arr[reverse_bits(i, levels)]
    # Radix-2 decimation-in-time FFT
    size = 2
    while size <= n:
        half_size = size // 2
        step = n // size
        for i in range(0, n, size):
            k = 0
            for j in range(i, i + half_size):
                temp = result[j + half_size] * e_arr[k]
                result[j + half_size] = result[j] - temp
                result[j] += temp
                k += step
        size *= 2
    return result


@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def fft_1d_arb(arr, fft_1d_r2=fft_1d_radix2_rbi):
    """1D FFT for arbitrary inputs using chirp z-transform"""
    arr = np.asarray(arr, dtype=np.complex128)
    n = len(arr)
    m = 1 << (ilog2(n) + 2)
    e_arr = np.empty(n, dtype=np.complex128)
    for i in range(n):
        e_arr[i] = cmath.exp(-1j * cmath.pi * (i * i) / n)
    result = np.zeros(m, dtype=np.complex128)
    result[:n] = arr * e_arr
    coeff = np.zeros_like(result)
    coeff[:n] = e_arr.conjugate()
    coeff[-n + 1:] = e_arr[:0:-1].conjugate()
    return fft_convolve(result, coeff, fft_1d_r2)[:n] * e_arr / m


@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def fft_convolve(a_arr, b_arr, fft_1d_r2=fft_1d_radix2_rbi):
    return fft_1d_r2(fft_1d_r2(a_arr) * fft_1d_r2(b_arr), False)


@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def fft_1d(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    if not n & (n - 1):
        return fft_1d_radix2_rbi(arr)
    else:
        return fft_1d_arb(arr)
```

Compared to the naïve DFT algorithm (`dft_1d()` which is fundamentally the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62383155/5218354)), you are gaining orders of magnitude, while you are still a typically a lot slower than `np.fft.fft()`.

[image: vs_dft]

The relative speed varies greatly depending on the input sizes.
For *power-of-2* inputs, this is typically within one order of magnitude of `np.fft.fft()`.

[image: pow2]

For non-*power-of-2*, this is typically within two orders of magnitude of `np.fft.fft()`.

[image: not-pow2]

For worst-case (prime numbers or so, here is power-of-2 + 1), this is a times as fast as `np.fft.fft()`.

[image: primes]

The non-linear behavior of the FFT timings are the result of the need for a more complex algorithm for arbitrary input sizes that are not *power-of-2*. This affects both this implementation and the one from `np.fft.fft()`, but `np.fft.fft()` contains a lot more optimizations which make it perform much better on average.

Alternate implementations of power-of-2 FFT are shown [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1pKDJFKASDA4XrnXQrRgvbRc8iueZG2dZ?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find a workaround. Now, keep in mind that functions like `numpy.fft.fft` have lots of convenience operations, so if you're not stuck like me, you should use them.

Following `njit` function does a `discrete fourier transform` on a `one dimensional array`:

```
import numba
import numpy as np
import cmath

def dft(wave=None):
    dft = np.fft.fft(wave)
    return dft

@numba.njit
def dft_njit(wave=None):
    N = len(wave)
    dft_njit = np.zeros(N, dtype=np.complex128)
    for i in range(N):
        series_element = 0
        for n in range(N):
            series_element += wave[n] * cmath.exp(-2j * cmath.pi * i * n * (1 / N))
        dft_njit[i] = series_element
    return dft_njit

if __name__ == '__main__':

    wave = [1,2,3,4,5]
    wave = np.array(wave)

    print(f' dft: \n{dft(wave=wave)}')
    print(f' dft_njit: \n{dft_njit(wave=wave)}')
```

Output:

```
 dft: 
[15. +0.j         -2.5+3.4409548j  -2.5+0.81229924j -2.5-0.81229924j
 -2.5-3.4409548j ]
 dft_njit: 
[15. +0.j         -2.5+3.4409548j  -2.5+0.81229924j -2.5-0.81229924j
 -2.5-3.4409548j ]
```

Answer (score 2):

The numba documentation mentioned that np.fft.fft is not support. A solution is to use [the objmode context](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/withobjmode.html?highlight=objmode#the-objmode-context-manager) to call python functions that are not supported yet. Only the part inside the objmode context will run in object mode, and therefore can be slow. For you particular case, this part will not be that slow because np.fft.fft is already very fast as pointed by @tstanisl as the first comment of the question. Here is as example

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np

@njit()
def compute_fft(x):
   y = np.zeros(., dtype=np.complex128) 
   with objmode(y='type[:]'):
      y = np.fft.fft(x)
   return y

@njit()
def main():
   ...
   x = np.random.randint(100)
   fft_x = compute_fft(x) 
   ...
```